# (Game of Life) How to loop through outer layer of a matrix without checking outside of it, simultaneously checking for neighbors?

Tags: c, matrix, logic, indexoutofboundsexception, conways-game-of-life

Each point in the matrix represents a cell, living or dead. I have to count how many ALIVE neighbors each cell has. I have a function that does the job, but it checks for cells outside its boundary.I don't know how I can simultaneously check for neighbors and keep track of edges without doing a massive amount of if-else statements.

```
void Neighbours(int rows, 
                int cols, cell world[rows][cols], 
                int neighbors[rows][cols]) {

//Loop through each cell in the matrix. 
for(int rCell = 0; rCell < rows; rCell++){
  for(int cCell = 0; cCell < cols; cCell++) {
    //Reset neighbor count for each cell.
    neighbors[rCell][cCell] = 0;
    //Check cell status in cell's vicinity of each cell. 
    for(int surroundR = -1; surroundR <= 1; surroundR++){
      for(int surroundC = -1; surroundC <= 1; surroundC ++) {
        //CONDITIONS
        //1. If the cell is alive,
        //2. if the cell is not itself,
        //3. if it does exist within the boundaries of the matrix.
        if(field[rCell - surroundR][cCell - surroundC].status == ALIVE) {
          if(!(surroundR  == 0 && surroundC  == 0) && (rCell-surroundR < rows) && (cCell-surroundC < cols) && (cCell-surroundC  >= 0) && (rCell-surroundR  >= 0)) {
            neighbors[rCell][cCell] += 1;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  } 
}
}
```

Comment: How about using first and last dummy columns and rows, initialised with some inactive value? If necessary add the inactive value to the possible values, with a special case treatment.

Comment: This is actually an algorithm question, more than a C programming one. What you are looking for is the most efficient way, algorithm-wise, to do these checks. Implementing "game of life" is kind of a classic problem so surely there's already someone who's given this some thought. I would advise to ask that question over at https://cs.stackexchange.com/. Then when you have the ideal theoretical algorithm, you can attempt to implement in C and then ask here when you run into implementation problems.

Comment: Please replace your C/C#/C++/Java code with equivalent pseudocode.

Comment: I think this is a question about programming, not algorithms. The algorithmic step is "check each of the neighbours" and you're asking how to implement this efficiently.

Comment: @Lundin As a regular user of CS SE, I'd say this is firmly off-topic there. The algorithm is "check the adjacent squares" and the question here is about how to implement that algorithm at the level of programming language statements (specifically, without lots of `if`s and `else`s). CS SE doesn't do "how should I implement this?"

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/86486/755, https://stackoverflow.com/q/48167910/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: @Lundin, can I make a request for the future?  In the future, if you suggest posting the question on another site, can you remind the poster not to cross-post?  You can suggest they delete the copy here before posting it elsewhere if they think it's a better fit on another site.  Hopefully that will provide a better experience for all, and avoid users from feeling they they're getting mixed messages.  thank you!

Comment: I'll remember in the future not to post the same thing.

Comment: By the way, the C way of representing the world is as an array of Booleans, i.e., `int`s such that `world[i][j]==1` if that square is alive and `0` if it's dead. Then, for a square that's not on the edge of the world, you can just say `neighbours[i][j] = world[i-1][j-1] + world[i-1][j] + world[i-1][j+1] + ...`, instead of using a bunch of `if (world[m][n].status==ALIVE)` conditionals.

Comment: @DavidRicherby No, the question is how to check the number of adjacent squares with the fewest number of comparisons/branches. That's a pure algorithm problem. Iterating through every single cell and check all adjacent squares each time simply cannot be the most effective way to solve this.

Comment: @D.W. It is up to each and every individual user to read the rules and scope of each site. I think it goes without saying that this question cannot be posted as-is on the CS site, since a C code implementation wouldn't be very relevant. It is rare that a question can be cross-posted across several sites while remaining a good on-topic question on all of them. That being said, contrary to popular belief there is actually no rule against cross-posting on the SE network. It is discouraged and frowned upon by many users, but there is no rule against it.

Comment: @Lundin New users rarely know what they're supposed to do. It would be helpful if you, as an experienced user, gave them more helpful advice.

Comment: @Lundin, well, the policies that I link to say that you should never cross-post the same question on multiple Stack Exchange sites (regardless of whether it is on-topic on all of them).  So I think there *is* a rule.  Here's the link again: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068; take a look at the first answer.  Anyway, as David Richerby says, we can probably help new users a bit more by elaborating a bit on what they should do, rather than assuming they'll know.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to handle this is to add two dummy rows and columns: a row above your matrix, a row below your matrix, a column to the left of your matrix, and a column to the right of your matrix. You set them to DEAD once and for all, and run your loops only on the cells in the original matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Always when you have this kind of check - before indexing into array check whether the indices are within the size of the array on which you are about to index. You have to do that first before indexing into array. Earlier you had undefined behavior due to accessing array index out of bound.

```
if( (rCell - surroundR) <= rows-1 && (cCell - surroundC)<= cols-1 && (rCell - surroundR)>=0 && (cCell - surroundC)>=0 ) {
   /* then do rest of work */

}
```

Comment: I could've had undefined behavior, but the following conditions made sure that didn't happen.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily sell some memory to save time by using an array containing one row on each side with only *dead* elements, and do the processing only in the inside. The algorithm becomes simpler with less risk of errors, but but whole code must be changed to add 2 lines and 2 rows:

```
void Neighbours(int rows, 
                int cols, cell world[rows][cols], 
                int neighbors[rows][cols]) {

//Loop through each cell in the matrix. 
for(int rCell = 1; rCell < rows-1; rCell++){   // limit to the interior
  for(int cCell = 1; cCell < cols-1; cCell++) {
     // remaining part of the loops is unchanged
```

Comment: That's a really interesting solution. However, I must have 20x20.

Answer (score 2):

One method is to pad the array with rows and columns of dead cells at the edges of the array.

Another method is to write separate pieces of code:

- One loop processes interior cells (omitting the edge rows and columns) of the array, checking all neighbors.
- One loop processes the top row, checking only actual neighbors of cells of the top row. Only cells interior to the row are processed, omitting the corners.
- Similarly, there is one loop for the bottom row, one for the left column, and one for the right column.
- The four corners are checked separately.

Although this is more code, it executes fewer checks than one loop checking for each cell. Note that that the loops for the top row and the bottom row may be combined (because they share the column coordinate), and the loops for the left edge and the right edge may be combined.

Additional reductions of the computational load are possible. For example, the counts of living cells in each 3*1 strip in the main array can be cached (in an auxiliary array or simply in variables in a carefully crafted loop) to be reused. Each such strip in the interior of the main array is used three times in counting the 3*3 squares around various cells, so caching their counts can eliminate some repeated work.

(Regarding padding: To use proper C code, you need two columns, one on the left and one on the right. However, if your C implementation supported accessing subarray elements out of bounds as long as the addressed element is in the complete array, or you manually map two dimensions into a one-dimensional array, then one padding column would suffice, since it would be both to the left of the left edge of the array proper and to the right of the right edge.)